# Sorting of filenames in the output file

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

I would like to know how to write output of numeric filenames (0.mp4,1.mp4...10.mp4,11.mp4) residing in a folder along with the path to an output text file in ascending order.
While I am able to write the output to the text file using the below batch script, the order of the file names in the output file is not sorted

```
for /r %f in (*.mp4) do echo %f >>out.txt
```

gives me the out.txt as

```
0.mp4
1.mp4
10.mp4
11.mp4
```

I need it as

```
0.mp4
1.mp4
2.mp4,
3.mp4 etc
```

.

Please help.

Comment: are the filenames always numbers?

Answer (score 0):

you can do a recursive ascending dir list and then do whatever you need to do, including printing to a file:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%m in ('dir /b /o:n /s ^| findstr /i ".mp4"') do (
    echo %%m>>out.txt
)
```